# Change gtkListStore model dynamically

Tags: python, pygtk

So I finally got around to understand how PyGTK really works and I'm working on a simple SQLite manager app.

To show the result of a query I'm using a gtk.ScrolledWindow with a gtk.TreeView. I've managed to add and even change the values in the ListStore object as I need, what I can't do is change the model of the ListStore object.

For example in one query I may have a result of two columns:

```
    self.query_results = gtk.ListStore(str,str)
    self.query_results.append(["1"],["John Doe"])
```

And in another one I may get more columns:

```
    self.query_results = gtk.ListStore(str,str,str,str)
    self.query_results.append(["20"],["Jane"],["jane@example.com"],["password"])
```

I know I can use stuff like

```
     self.query_results = gtk.ListStore(*[str]*len(columns))
```

But aparently gtk.ListStore cannot have it's model changed after being created, so how would I update this query table? Do I need to destroy the Treeview and draw it again everytime I run a different query?

Thanks and this is my first question on StackOverflow so excuse any mistakes/posting guidelines I didn't follow.

Comment: Check out [libgda4](http://www.gnome-db.org/) - it does what you want already and has a ListStore interface that communicates directly with the underlying database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`gtk.TreeView.set_model`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--set-model) to assign a new model to a TreeView. So you can generate a new model for each set of results, and then set the TreeView to show that model.

Comment: Curiously I figured that out 2 minutes ago and got it working. Thanks for the help thats exactly what I was doing.

Comment: Don't forget to submit the answer. (check the tick in the left)